# Are there any quests from mobs in Mount Hyjal?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mount Hyjal, are there any quests that are started from mobs drops?

If so, what are these quests called (links please)?

(I missed a quest in that area... I got 114/115. are there any quests hidden?)

Comment: I would advise you to make the question a bit more general and ask how to figure out what quest you are missing for an achievement. Any possible answer should answer this one, but also work when you miss quests in other zones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** [Here's a listing of all quests](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=cr=6:166;crs=1:4;crv=0:0#0-3+12+1) started by an item drop added in Cataclysm. As you can see, there aren't many, and they're almost entirely in Vashj'ir (with a few in Uldum and Deepholme).

More likely, you've missed a hub. I'd suggest trying [WoWheads 'personalized search' feature](http://www.wowhead.com/blog=174638/new-feature-personalized-searches) to see which quests in the zone you haven't completed.

Comment: very good tip thx

Comment: +1: Mount Hyjal has about 15-20 more quests than you need for the achievement, so you definitely missed a hub.